# Place a list/recyclerview over a bottomsheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Can we create a layout where we have a recyclerview over the top of a hidden bottomsheet view such that whenever the bottom sheet slides up and expands, the recyclerview aligns titself just above the bottom sheet and not hide behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this. You just have to use the BottomSheetCallback on your BottomSheetBehavior, like this:

```
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(yourLayoutWithBottomSheetBehavior);
bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) yourRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();        
        layoutParams.height = bottomSheet.getTop();
        yourRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);        
        yourRecyclerView.requestLayout();
});
```

In the onSlide method you always get the current top of the bottom sheet if you change state or drag it.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrapped my *content* view inside an another view ( *rootContent* ) only for the scope to get the height, but you can get it in a better way. Then in the BottomSheetCallback

```
  mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
                content.getLayoutParams().height = rootContent.getHeight();
            }else {
                content.getLayoutParams().height = rootContent.getHeight() - bottomSheet.getHeight();
            }
            content.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can acheive this . Just make **RelativeLayout** as parent layout then add **include** your view/layout in it, and assign property **alignParentBottom=
"true"**. Then include your **RecyclerView** and add **layout_above="included_layout_id"**